# Memoir : Warnings "The material used in the headers is too large" w/ accented titles

Tags: header-footer, memoir, warnings, height

With memoir class, the default headers height seems unsuitable for accented titles of chapter/section. The result doesn't look strange, but Warnings `The material used in the headers is too large
(14.1595pt) for the given head height (13.6pt)` with additionnal `Overfull \vbox (0.5595pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []"` are generated for every page concerned.

I've added

```
\setlength{\headheight}{14.2pt}
```

in my preambule, but I don't know if it could pose others problems of margin ?

MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Titre accentué}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be the uppercase form with accented letters. If you can accept non uppercase, insert `\nouppercaseheads` in your preamble and the warning will disappear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `memoir` changing the `\headheight` will not affect the position of the baseline of the header text. Increasing the `\headheight` allows more vertical space for the text. Changing `\headheight` will only alter the spacing between the top of the page and the baseline of the header.

Comment: Good to know ! So there's no problem with my solution I suppose.