# How to do the memoir headings fix but not have my text going over the page bottom margins?

Tags: margins, memoir, framed

I am using a fix `\setlength{\headheight}{14.0pt}` for the `memoir` package I found on [Memoir : Warnings "The material used in the headers is too large" w/ accented titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310493/memoir-warnings-the-material-used-in-the-headers-is-too-large-w-accented-ti) but when I use it, my pages bottom goes out of the text screen:

[image]

If I remove the memoir headings fix `\setlength{\headheight}{14.0pt}` the page layout is correct as showed:

[image]

When I compile it with `\setlength{\headheight}{14.0pt}` I got

`No errors. No warnings. No bad boxes.`

How to do the memoir headings fix `\setlength{\headheight}{14.0pt}` but not have my text going over the page bottom margins as showed on first figure?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

% Memoir : Warnings “The material used in the headers is too large” w/ accented titles
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310493/memoir-warnings-the-material-used-in-the-headers-is-too-large-w-accented-ti
\setlength{\headheight}{14.0pt}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
Este documento e seu código-fonte são exemplos de referência de uso da
classe \textsf{abntex2} e do pacote \textsf{abntex2cite}. O documento
exemplifica a elaboração de trabalho acadêmico (tese, dissertação e
outros do gênero) produzido conforme a ABNT NBR 14724:2011
\emph{Informação e documentação - Trabalhos acadêmicos -
Apresentação}.

A expressão ``Modelo Canônico'' é utilizada para indicar que  não é
modelo específico de nenhuma universidade ou instituição, mas que
implementa tão somente os requisitos das normas da ABNT. Uma lista
completa das normas observadas pelo  é apresentada em .

Sinta-se convidado a participar do projeto ! Acesse o site do projeto
em . Também fique livre para conhecer, estudar, alterar e redistribuir
o trabalho do , desde que os arquivos modificados tenham seus nomes
alterados e que os créditos sejam dados aos autores originais, nos
termos da ``The Project Public License'. Encorajamos que sejam
realizadas customizações específicas deste exemplo para universidades
e outras instituições --- como capas, folha de aprovação, etc. Porém,
recomendamos que ao invés de se alterar diretamente os arquivos do ,
distribua-se arquivos com as respectivas customizações. Isso permite
que futuras versões do ~não se tornem automaticamente incompatíveis
com as customizações promovidas. Consulte par mais informações.
Esperamos, sinceramente, que o  aprimore a qualidade do trabalho que
você produzirá, de modo que o principal esforço seja concentrado no
principal: na contribuição científica. Sinta-se convidado a participar
do projeto ! Acesse o site do projeto em . Também fique livre para
conhecer, estudar, alterar e redistribuir o trabalho do , desde que os
arquivos modificados tenham seus nomes alterados e que os créditos
sejam dados aos autores originais, nos termos da ``The  Project Public
License'. Encorajamos que sejam realizadas customizações específicas
deste exemplo para universidades e outras instituições --- como capas,
folha de aprovação, etc. Porém, recomendamos que ao invés de se
alterar diretamente os arquivos do , distribua-se arquivos com as
respectivas customizações. Isso permite que futuras versões do ~não se
tornem automaticamente incompatíveis com as customizações promovidas.
Consulte par mais informações. Esperamos, sinceramente, que o
aprimore a qualidade do trabalho que você produzirá, de modo que o
principal esforço seja concentrado no principal: na contribuição
científica.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is well known that the showframe package does not work correctly with the memoir class. Try memoirs page style showlocs which does the same.

Comment: Also use the memoir interface to change the layout instead of manipulating individual lengths.

Comment: @daleif thanks! I used `\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}` instead of `\usepackage{showframe}` and it worked correctly [Print page margins of a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14508/print-page-margins-of-a-document). When I used `\pagestyle{showlocs}` from memoir on the test file it showed some strange frames, but not all of them. But when I put `\pagestyle{showlocs}` on my full template with memoir, it showed nothing/no frames.

Comment: Remember last pagestyle is the active one, and memoir uses specific pagestyles on certain pages